# Why is Ken so cheap?

Tags: super-puzzle-fighter-2

I always hear that Ken is God Tier/broken/super cheap. What exactly about his block pattern makes him cheap though? It seems like Akuma/Devilot's block patterns are more random and dangerous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare Ken's pattern in column 4 vs other characters.  Column 4 must be cleared to allow more blocks to be played.  Consider full pattern and half pattern x2 attacks.

If Ken drops his full pattern, you require 4 different color breaks.  If Ken drops half pattern x2, you need 2x2 (r, g, r, g) color breaks.

```
Full    Halfx2
4       2x2     Ken
4       2x2     Devilot (70% damage)
4       2x2     Akuma (70% damage)
2       1       Donovan
2x2     2x2     Sakura
2       1       ChunLi
2       1       Morrigan
2       1       Hsien-Ko
2       1       Felicia
1       1       Ryu
1       1       Dan
```

There you have it really, Ken's pattern attacks column 4 as hard as Devilot and Akuma, but without the damage penalty.

Ken's Pattern:
[image: Ken's Pattern]

Ryu's Pattern (note the easy to attack column 4):
[image: Ryu's Pattern]

---

You might be playing puzzle fighter hd, which seems to have had balancing changes according to [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20120502200257/http://www.sirlin.net/articles/balancing-puzzle-fighter.html).  If the article is correct, much of this column 4 analysis still holds:

1. Ken still better than Akuma and Devilot (just a little less so).
2. Ryu brought up into the rest of the pack, now is better than Dan.
3. Hsien-Ko now as good as Ken (aka Overpowered!)

Comment: Good explanation; it's all about the single column, not the rows. Makes sense since the rows are rarely even. I shall have to bar friends from playing Ken now that I know why :)

Comment: @BenBrocka let the beginners play Ken.  Everyone else should aspire to win with Dan.

Comment: Good point. I tried so hard to beat a friend with Dan. I usually play Hsien-Ko. Looks like the non Dan/Ken/Ryu/Akuma/Devilot characters are pretty well balanced?

Comment: Outside of Ken/Ryu/Dan, the remaining characters are fairly well balanced with respect to column 4 (imo even Akuma and Devilot are balanced due to their damage penalty).  There are other aspects to the game: compare ChunLi and Sakura's pattern.  You'd only take ChunLi if you were trying to get them to hit you harder (dan style)...

Comment: Oh, yeah, I'm playing HD. I guess it's no wonder I never found Ken that overpowered. I think Ryu's pattern is the same though, I'll have to check

Comment: Wow - that linked article is **fascinating** - thank you!